# cannot open database login failed for user;asp.net;codesmith

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, codesmith, .nettiers

A random error happens on the production environment 
cannot open database  login failed for user 
I'm using windows authentication and the code generated by the codesmith netTiers and the production environment has Windows 2008 R2 and SQL server 2008 R2 and 8GB of RAM 
we have about 300 users connected to the application at a time and we use NetworkService Identity in the application pool with .Net frame work 4.0

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Please post your code with connection string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to take time debugging the issue, then create a user in SQL server and change your connectionstring and remove the integrated security parameter

```
connectionString="Server=servername;Database=DBNAME;User ID=newsser;pwd=yourpass;"
```

Comment: This issue is random and i can't catch the case that do this issue, and it happened in the production at the client and the client restrict me to use the windows authentication connection string ...